# HTML5 Motion Tracking using <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I am working on HTML5 motion tracking and currently I am using drawing context's method drawImage to capture current frame and add "tracker" object on it.

You can see example code here:

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

    var cat = new Image();
    cat.src = 'cat.png';
    cat.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(cat, 150, 190);
    }
```

But my solution should support Safari iOS browser as well, but this is from browser's documentation:

> Note: Video as a source for the canvas drawImage() method is not
>   currently supported on iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html

So they suggested the following solution:

> Using video as a source for drawImage() involves a lot of system
>   resources. Generally speaking, video is best displayed using the video
>   element, not the canvas element. To composite canvas text or
>   animations over moving video, it’s better to use a video element
>   behind the canvas—the video shows through the transparent background
>   of the canvas without the overhead of displaying video on the canvas
>   itself.

The coordinates of followed objects comes from JSON file (I have information for each frame), here is JSON content for one frame:

```
"frames": {
    "0": [{
        "i": 0,
        "x": 686.356,
        "y": 192.797
    },
    {
        "i": 2,
        "x": 1036.4,
        "y": 194.135
    },
    {
        "i": 3,
        "x": 566,
        "y": 113.5
    },
    {
        "i": 4,
        "x": 357,
        "y": 98
    }],
```

(Here I follow 4 objects)

So I am thinking, what would be better approach? To capture every frame and add following object on canvas, or use transparent canvas and draw ONLY following objects.

If my explanation is bad, you can check the following video: http://codeazur.com.br/stuff/motiontracking/

By "following objects" I mean orange items.

Comment: Hi Kav , I am struggling to do this , can you provide source code for This if you found the solution, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably an easy decision!

It's a case of right-tool-for-the-job: video tag for video and canvas tag for drawing.

Since you have json coordinates for each frame, play the video in the background and put your orange tracker on a canvas that sits right on top of the video.

You can use video metrics to sync your frame with your tracking drawing.  I assume you already have this part of your solution, but here is reference to video metrics anyway: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics